# transcribe a phone recording

Tags: telephony, transcription

There is a certain organization that periodically provides information in the form of a recorded message on a "hotline".  Is there any open source solution (or set of components that could be "wired" together) that would allow me to present this information in text form on a web page?

Answer (score 0):

Since it's the really easy part, I'm going to assume you can fetch the audio from the "hotline", i.e. you have direct access to the actual audio samples.

The hard part is transcribing the audio.  You can start by having a look at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_speech_recognition_software) and follow the links from there.  One solution you could use would be [CMU Sphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/).  Google and other related search tools such as Google Scholar are likely to become your close friends :)

While there are a number of voice recognition engines available, their accuracy is far from perfect.

Comment: Thanks but I also need a way to call the hotline and capture the audio.  If I had direct access to the audio files, I probably would not have added unnecessary complexity to my question, right?  If I wanted to add unnecessary complexity I could have gone into all kinds of details about the content of the audio, the history of the hotline, its politics, etc.

Comment: You're welcome.  I think you should consider breaking up the problem into smaller parts, such as dialing a phone from your computer, recording the audio, performing OCR, serving the OCR result through a web-page, and so on.  You should then put in a bit of effort and research ways of solving the individual problems on your own using tools like Google Search, Google Scholar, Wikipedia, etc.  That will help you in formulating a useful question that people here can answer.  I think that it's unlikely that anyone here is going to do your problem analysis and research for you.